# NodeJS MySQL DB connection fail

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, shared-hosting

thank you in advance for the help.

I am using nodejs v16.13.1 and mysql 5.7.37-cll-lve.
my nodejs app is currently on my local machine and my mysql db is on a remote server. I want to connect to the remote mysql but, I keep getting this error:

> Access denied for user ''@'mylocalcomputerip' (using password: YES)

I am using shared hosting btw.

What is weird is that the user is not showing and I know it is correctly being used. as well the the connection trying to connect to my local ip despite me putting in my server ip.

I tried using one of the nameservers and then it gives a timeout.

this is how I am trying to connect to the remote db.

```js
createConnection(){
        const conn = mysql.createConnection({
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            port: process.env.DB_PORT
        })

        conn.connect(err => {
            if(err) throw err
            console.log("Connected")
        })
        return conn
    }
```

The host is the shared ip.

The username is the user I created to interact with the db.

The password is the password for the username.

The database is the database that I'm trying to connect to.

The port is the default port 3306 for mysql dbs.

Any kind of knowledge or insight to what I'm doing wrong or don't know about would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "What is weird is that the user is not showing and I know it is correctly being used" — Really? It is not typical for databases on shared hosting (or any well secured database) to be directly accessible from local development environments. Have you checked the permissions to make sure that `user ''@'mylocalcomputerip'` really does have access?

Comment: can such a user even exist since it isn't using the server ip it is using my public ip? Even if this user does exist should it even matter since this is not the user I configured/created to interact with the database that I created. I did add the user I created to the allowed users and I whitelisted my public ip as well. I am using a cPanel MySQL database.

Comment: "can such a user even exist since it isn't using the server ip it is using my public ip" — Yes. Maybe you need to read up on the basics of how authentication in MySQL/MariaDB exists.

Comment: "Even if this user does exist should it even matter since this is not the user I configured/created to interact with the database that I created" — You said you were trying to make the connection to your data from your development environment. The request from your development environment is going to be coming from your public IP. If you've created a user which isn't allowed to be from your public IP, then you've created a user which isn't the one you're connecting from!

Comment: This is probably going to ruin my rep but I completely spaced out. I found the issue. The object that the "createConnection" function takes has a key of "user" not "username" didn't even bother checking that. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!! The object that is passed to the function createConnection uses a "user" key and not "username".